# How to load json with focus event only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have basic event with `focus` as below:

```js
(document).on("focus", '#checkin,#checkout', function() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    //load here...
  });
});
```

and I want to load my json data, actually code is work as expect when I focus on my input .json data has been loading but I see result if I focus on my input twice..

how can I load my json data **when I focus my input once** ?

[Plunker Demo With Full Project](http://plnkr.co/edit/KPUPjzKG0sooF2WZIc6h?p=preview)

Comment: All relevant code belongs directly into your question.

Comment: What could that possibly mean? That you should go read [ask], probably.

Comment: An apart from that, it doesn’t look like you are actually waiting for your AJAX request to finish ... so you are only initializing your date pickers with the result form the _previous_ AJAX request (which on the first focus event obviously does not even exist.)

Comment: You need to focus on input tag when load the page or what?

Comment: when load to my input

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the warning actually I don't know how must be my jquery now but I will try to something

Comment: just use focusin or focusout

Comment: nothing change with `focusin`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag to test if the event was already fired or not:

```
var focused = false;
$(document).on("focus", '#checkin,#checkout', function() {
  if (!focused) {
    console.log('focused!!');
    focused = true;
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var focused = false;
$(document).on("focus", '#checkin,#checkout', function() {
  if (!focused) {
    console.log('focused!!');
    focused = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkin" />

<input id="checkout" />
```

Or as alternatives you can use [jQuery `.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to remove the event handler or [`.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind it only once.

Comment: thanks in this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/j0cUMeSHNlEC5lf8C3LD?p=preview

I tried but it works as before

Comment: I think problem is aparting from datepicker my focus function works too as your code but problem is this: my datepicker is opening when I focus it twice but it must twice when I focus only once

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code when get the json data :

```
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
     element.find('#checkin').focus();
     element.find('#checkout').focus();
  });
```

Comment: real problem is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zp2zs6m9QzOY6J6lXwqx?p=preview if you focus input you are gonna see the problem..datepicker is showing when I focus on my input only once but it is showing when I focus twice.